# select query taking long time in postgres foreign tables

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

My select query taking long time in postgres foreign tables. It is taking 15sec in MSSQL server.

PostgreSQL 13.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by Debian clang version 12.0.1, 64-bit

I am querying two different database tables with the help of fdw

I was created extention for postgres cross database query

Both tables are from same server but different database

Here is my Query

```
select *
   FROM table1
   join table2
       on table1."ID" = table2."ID"
limit 1000
```

Here is my explain plan.

```
Limit  (cost=210.94..239.96 rows=60 width=3754)
Hash Join  (cost=210.94..239.96 rows=60 width=3754)
Hash Cond: ((table1.""ID"")::text = (table2.""ID"")::text)
Foreign Scan on table1   (cost=100.00..126.38 rows=546 width=126)
Hash  (cost=110.66..110.66 rows=22 width=3628)
Foreign Scan on table2   (cost=100.00..110.66 rows=22 width=3628)
```

Let me know how to improve my select query performance

I was tried increase of work_mem and creating indexes on ID columns on two tables but no luck.

Here is my Explain Analyze

```
Limit  (cost=210.94..239.96 rows=60 width=3754) (actual time=389787.002..389790.955 rows=1000 loops=1)
Hash Join  (cost=210.94..239.96 rows=60 width=3754) (actual time=389787.000..389790.879 rows=1000 loops=1)
Hash Cond: ((table1.""ID"")::text = (table1.""ID"")::text)
Foreign Scan on table1  (cost=100.00..126.38 rows=546 width=126) (actual time=12.722..13.047 rows=4065 loops=1)
Hash  (cost=110.66..110.66 rows=22 width=3628) (actual time=389773.386..389773.388 rows=51371319 loops=1)
Buckets: 33554432 (originally 1024)  Batches: 4 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 4737857kB
Foreign Scan on table2  (cost=100.00..110.66 rows=22 width=3628) (actual time=54.429..332881.164 rows=51371319 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.212 ms
Execution Time: 392158.638 ms
```

Please any one help me to resolve this

Comment: What PostgreSQL version do you use and what kind of foreign data wrapper do you use? From the query plan is pretty clear that the LIMIT 1000 is done on the local server and not on the remote one. Without details about your setup, it's impossible to tell why.

Comment: By the way, these are two foreign tables, that could explain why all data has to come over to the local server before the join can be done. When both tables are on the same remote database, you could create a view on that database, using the join. And then create a single foreign table using this view instead of two foreign tables on two tables.

Comment: @FrankHeikens,                                                                                                 
     PostgreSQL 13.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by Debian clang version 12.0.1, 64-bit

I am querying two different database tables with the help of fdw

I was created extention for postgres cross database query 

Both tables are from same server but different database

Comment: In that case the database has no other option then first collecting all the data from the two remote databases and then join the two results. That will be slow. Using different fetch settings might speed it up a little bit, but you still need a lot of data

Comment: Please edit the question and add new information there. Also, tell us which FDW in which version you are using. If the tables are on different aervers, how do you query them with a single query in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Its worked after adding fetch size to the server

Comment: You might want to ANALYZE your foreign tables as well, the query plan is absolutely wrong about the estimates on these tables. However, not all foreign data wrappers support ANALYZE.

Comment: You should probably set use_remote_estimate for the server.